# I can't send auto emails from App script with my Google workspace account as I could using my personal gmail account

Tags: email, google-apps-script, automation

I am having issues with App script. I just got a google workspace account but I can't seem to send auto emails using App script. All the emails I tried to send were blocked and I received notification emails about this. The template email is fine and when I click 'on form submit'and then 'run' it sends too. but then i receive a bunch of emails from google saying the emails was blocked. Is there something I need to change in settings to fix this?

Comment: Have you looked in the admin panel.  Perhaps there's a security setting.

Comment: What do the notifications say? Did you run your script from the script editor first and authorize it on the new account? Did you have to activate any APIs in the old account to use the script? Can you share the script?